# Is it okay to use Java for the backend of large scale server management?

Tags: java, server, client, client-server

So I have about 6 years of experience with Java, and consider myself to be fairly proficient at it. I was recently messing around with some server-client connection stuff, and realized that I could build something at a large scale to handle lots of connections. Is it okay to use Java as a backend for a large scale server that handles large amounts of separate clients? Is it so bad of a language to use for this, that you would suggest learning an entirely different one instead? Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with using java as a backend for a large server, but it would likely be done more efficiently in a lower level language.

Comment: large scale systems effectively use Java at the backend. Java is not just a language - it is a computing platform and coding ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Java fits perfectly in the backend. There are several large frameworks which are well supported by their communities. I mention a few here

- [Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html)
- [Spring Framework](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/)
- [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/)